# Get conda environment variable inside Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, conda

With my conda environment activated I set an environment variable with the command

```
conda env config vars set ROOT_DIRECTORY=$PWD
```

Now, if a run `echo $ROOT_DIRECTORY` the output shows `/home/augusto/myproject`

How can I get that variable inside Jupyter Notebook? I tried with the command below, but the output shows `None`.

```py
import os
print(os.getenv('ROOT_DIRECTORY'))
```

By the way, I have shure that Jupyter Notebook are using the correct Kernel. Running the above code inside a `.py` file works correctly, i.e. the output shows `/home/augusto/myproject`.

Answer (score 0):

Find env dir

```
jupyter kernelspec list
    
cd path_to_kernel_dir

sudo nano kernel.json
```

Add environment section to json

json should look something like this

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/home/jupyter-admin/.conda/envs/tf/bin/python3",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {"LD_LIBRARY_PATH":"/home/jupyter-admin/.conda/envs/tf/lib/"},
 "display_name": "tf_gpu",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```